# sort array of objects in a forEach method (natural sort)

Tags: angular, typescript

as you can see in the code below, I am trying to sort an array of objects but nothing happens.
Do I need another function to sort natural alphanumeric? Or is the forEach Method a problem?

```
   element.items[x] = [
  {
    "title": "033 - Riegel, Freizeitaktivitäten",
  },
  {
    "title": "011 - Psychosomatischer Einstellungsfragebogen (ZPID-Standard 9001406)",
  },
  {
    "title": "047 - Wunschprobe (ZPID-Standard 9004592)",
  },
  {
    "title": "014 - Exploration II, allgemeine und vergangene Lebenssituation",
  },
  {
    "title": "006 - Beurteilung des Gesamteindrucks",
  },
  {
    "title": "015 - Exploration III, allgemeine und zukünftige Lebenssituation",
  },
  {
    "title": "016 - Befragung zur Familie und Angehörigen",
  }
]


this.dokumentation.forEach( element => {
  console.log(element.items.sort((a, b) => (a.title > b.title) ? 1 : -1));
});
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] that shows the actual problem (or at least add a more elaborate description other than _"nothing happens"_)

Comment: you want to say `this.element.items.forEach(el=>el.sort((a,b)=>(a.title>b.title)=1:-1));` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the string and get number from string and then sort the array:

```
let sortedArray = arr.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.title) - parseInt(b.title));
console.log(sortedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use for each while we can use sort directly

```
let sortedElements = element.items[x].sort((a, b) => (a.title > b.title) ? 1 : -1);?
console.log(sortedElements);
```